# How to insert multiple dummy records with same data for column of type bytea in PostgreSQL?

Tags: bulkinsert, database-performance, postgresql-9.3, bytea

I want to insert 10000 records into Postgresql.

Columns - `bytea (Primary key), varchar, varchar`

Primary key should be different for each row. How can I do it using insert query or pgscript?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Augh, `bytea` primary key? What? Why? I wrote a simple extension for generating random bytea values, which you can find with the obvious Google search. But I can't imagine why you'd want a bytea pk.

Comment: I found the solution. Converted uuid to varchar and replaced '-' with '' and used decode(string,'hex') to return bytea. Thanks

Comment: Used while loop to insert 1000 records